# Prevent duplicate entries on Parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am building an android app with Facebook login, once logged, it'll save information from Facebook to Parse like Facebook ID, name and profile picture. Is there a way to make a column unique so that it can only have 1 kind of FB ID? or check if FB ID exist in my User table? I know it might seem like a very general request, but I've been googling for hours and can't find any specific solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already faced this problem in iOS, and seems that Android can be solved in the same way.
So, you can mix the FB API with the parse function

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(String facebookId, String accessToken, Date expirationDate, LogInCallback callback)
```

relying to facebook app you can obtain the *facebookId*, *accessToken* ( i think that for the expirationDate you can set a far date, like what i've done for iOS )

Another solution is:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(Arrays.asList(Permissions.User.EMAIL),
                    this, new LogInCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                            Do your stuff...
                        }
                    });
```

**it should automatically** detect if an user with that facebook id already exist in your _User table or not ( i can confirm this on iOS, you can check if the user is new or still exist with `user.isNew()` ). If you need you could also save the retrieved facebookId in a separated field, but i think you could avoid it for this scope

Hope it helps